# Google Apps Script to Unhide Rows in a Range

Tags: google-apps-script

I have an extensive Excel Spreadsheet (with numerous VBA scripts included) that I am converting to Google Sheets. I can not for the life of me figure out the GAS syntax on one of my VBA scripts. I have a range of cells, say A7:N56, that is just a table for the user to enter data. In this range, I only have rows 7-26 visible, and rows 27-56 are hidden (just for visual simplicity). If all of the rows that are visible are filled with data by the user, I want a button that the user can press to "Add Rows", which will then unhide the number of rows they want to "add". Following is the VBA equivalent that I have written:

```
Sub AddRows()
    Dim Answer As Integer
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim r As Range
    Dim Counter As Integer
           
    Do
        Answer = InputBox("How many rows would you like to add (1-20)?")
    Loop Until Answer >= 0 And Answer < 20
     
    Set rng = Range("$A$7:$N$56")
    Counter = 1
    
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        If r.EntireRow.Hidden And Counter <= Answer Then
            r.EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Counter = Counter + 1
        End If
    Next r
    
    For Each r In rng.Rows
        If r.RowHeight > 10 Then
            r.RowHeight = r.RowHeight - (Answer / 3)
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

I can't for the life of me figure out the syntax to make this work in Google Apps Scripts. Thank for for any assistance!

I have some of the script done. I just can't figure out the syntax to loop through the range, find the first hidden row and unhide the number of needed rows.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    function AddRows() {
        
        do { 
          var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
          var result = ui.prompt("How many rows would you like to add (0-30)?", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
          var button = result.getSelectedButton();
          var numRows = result.getResponseText();
    
        } while (numRows < 0 || numRows > 30);
       
        var rng = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A7:N56')
        var Counter = 1
        var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
        var Sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
        var LastRow = rng.getLastRow();
        for (i = 7; i <= LastRow; i++) {
          var statusRange = Sheet.getRange("A" + i);
        }  
    }
```

This will unhide all the rows that are hidden.

*edit: Actually this does nothing besides prompt the user for the number of rows to "add". I did have some code that would unhide all the hidden rows, but I have tried so many things, I'm not sure which it was.

Comment: What do you have so far in App Script? Does any part of it work?

Comment: OP edited to include the script so far.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this isn't exactly what you want but perhaps it will start a
dialog between you and us.

```
function AddRows() {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange("A7:N56").getValues();
  let resp = ui.prompt("How many rows would you like to add (0-30)?", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
    sh.(sh.showRows(getActiveCell().getRow(),parseInt(resp.getResponseText()));
  }    
}
```

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)
- [javascript reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)
- [Learn More](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info)

Comment: Thanks, Coop. I haven't been able try your solution yet, but the only thing that I can say for sure is that I do not need to "insert" any rows in the sheet. The rows are already there. I just need to unhide them. The reason that they are hidden is because there are only a few times periodically that the user will need to enter data in those rows. There is totaling info below the range. What I do if the user needs more than 20 rows, I unhide the rows that I need and then shrink the row height of all the rows in the range so that it prints neatly all on one sheet of paper. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thanks again, Cooper. To elaborate a little on my previous post, what I need to do is loop through rows 7-56 and find the first hidden row, unhide it, then loop and unhide each subsequent row until the number of rows needed by the user is reached. My excel VBA script above works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT to the rescue... here is code from chatGPT that works. If anyone has suggestions to make it more efficient, that would be welcomed. Thanks!

```
function AddRows() {
    
  do { 
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    var result = ui.prompt("How many rows would you like to add (0-30)?", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    var button = result.getSelectedButton();
    var numRows = result.getResponseText();
  } while (numRows < 0 || numRows > 30);

  if ((result.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.CANCEL) || (numRows == 0)) {
    return;
  } 
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 7;
  var endRow = 56;
  var neededRows = numRows;
  var firstHiddenRow = startRow;

  for (var i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
    if (sheet.isRowHiddenByUser(i)) {
      firstHiddenRow = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  for (var i = firstHiddenRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
    if (numRows <=0) {
      break;
    }
    sheet.showRows(i);
    numRows--;
  }
  for (var i = startRow; i <= endRow; i++) {
    var currentHeight = sheet.getRowHeight(i);
    if (currentHeight > 15) {
      sheet.setRowHeight(i, (currentHeight - (currentHeight * (neededRows/50))))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that posting ChatGPT-genrated content is [currently banned on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/10871073).